# adding hours and minutes to 24 hour time in R

Tags: r, datetime, chron

I`m trying to find a way to create a column of the hours of arrival of different individuals from 18:30, by adding the hours and minutes to 18:30, but it doesn`t work, and each time I try to convert the column format, of the hours and minutes I want to add, from "factor" to a time format (such as chron or POSIXct)it adds today`s date and I want to add only the hours and minutes without considering date.

For example, I want to add 03:38 hours to 18:30, which will be 22:08. So, I want to find a way to have a column with all the final hours (hours of arrival of each individual). another example is adding 00:47 hours to 18:30 which is 19:17.

I tried to do it by converting the hours+minutes to a numeric format and than add it to 18.5 (which is 18:30, just in a numeric format), and I reached final hours, but they are in a numeric format, and I wish them to be in an hour format. For example:

I added 3.6425980 (which is 03:38) to 18.5 (which is 18:30) and the final hour was 22.14260 (which is 22:08), but I don`t know how to convert 22.14260 to 22:08.
I need to do it for a lot of data, so I need a code that does one of the above things.

Can someone help me?

thanks!

Comment: `chron` times don't have a date attached - `times(paste("18:30", ":00"))` .  Also, what do you want to happen if the time laps into the next day - 10pm + 3hrs = 1am the next day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use `lubridate`

```
time <- c("18:30", "18:30")
duration <- c("3:38", "00:47")

library(lubridate)
hms(hm(time) + hm(duration), roll = T)
#[1] "22H 8M 0S"  "19H 17M 0S"
```